# How to find elements that match multiple conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

What I need to do is find all a elements on the page
that contain "tag" in the href property and the text of the element contains certain word.

For example

```
<a href="/my/tag/item2">cars</a>
```

I know I can get all a elements with tag in the href like this:

```
$("a[href*=tag]");
```

I can also find all a elements with 'cars' in the text like this:

```
$("a:contains('cars')");
```

But how do I combine these 2 conditions into a single statement that says:
Find all a elements that contain 'tag' in the href and contain 'cars' in the text?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried `$("a[href*=tag]:contains('cars')");`?

You can go on and on forever that way, i.e.

```
$("a.className.anotherClass[href*=tag][title=test]:contains('cars'):visible");
```

Answer (score 5):

As the other guys said or, if the two conditions need to be applied separately, with some other code in between for example, then ...

```
var $tags = $("a[href*=tag]");
```

then later ...

```
var $carTags = $tags.filter(":contains('cars')");
```

`.filter()` is the generalized method for reducing an existing jQuery selection.

Like many other jQuery methods `.filter()` returns a jQuery object so it will chain :

```
var $foo = $("a[href*=tag]").filter(":contains('cars')").filter(".myClass");
```

`.filter()` is also good for reasons I wasn't about to explain, and I don't need to because @bažmegakapa has just done so very eloquently.

Comment: Another nice feature I did now know about.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers show fine and working examples. But there is an interesting quirk here, the distinction between [native CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) (that are also supported by the native `querySelectorAll()`) and [selectors defined by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/).

Mixing them might not be fortunate, because then the much quicker native engine cannot be used. For example on [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) the jQuery docs state:

> Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method.

For this reason, you might better off querying with the native method and then [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) by using any jQuery specific selectors:

```
var $res = $("a[href*=tag]").filter(":contains('cars')");
```

Comment: +1 Nice explanation. Should be on every jQuery newbie's reading list.